# Missing users in Centrify active directory

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to list out all users in AD via dscl:

```
dscl localhost -list /CentrifyDC/Default/Users
```

it lists some users, but I know there are some users which are not in that list and I'm actually able to find these manually via

```
dscl localhost -read /CentrifyDC/Default/Users/%username%
```

Why I'm not getting the full list of all users? Is there any way how particular users can be hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following thread, `dscl . -list` is limited to 256 results and so is not guaranteed show all results:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303561/list-of-all-users-and-groups

If you have Centrify installed then you can get a list of all AD users using the command:

```
adquery user
```

This will give you a list of accounts with some basic information like username, uid:gid, home paths. 
If you want to output just a list of usernames, use:

```
adquery user -n
```

If you want to output all users and all attributes, use:

```
adquery user -A
```

Similarly, you can use similar syntax above to get a list of AD groups as well:

```
adquery group
```